# Destroy and reinit Swiper instance when an attribute is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using the following JS code in a Gutenberg block that displays a Swiper slider:

```
const containerRef = useRef(null);
const swiperRef = useRef(null);
const {
    attributes: { images, fx, auto },
    setAttributes,
} = props;

useEffect(() => {
    if (swiperRef.current) {
        console.log(swiperRef.current);
        // Destroy Swiper instance when updating.
        swiperRef.current.destroy(true, true);
    }
    // Init Swiper instance.
    swiperRef.current = new Swiper(containerRef.current, {
        modules: [Autoplay, Navigation, EffectFade],
        loop: true,
        effect: fx,
        fadeEffect: {
            crossFade: true
        },
        centeredSlides: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        observer: true,
        autoplay: auto ? {
            delay: 3000,
            disableOnInteraction: false,
            pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
        } : false,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.slider-navigation .slider-next',
            prevEl: '.slider-navigation .slider-prev',
        }
    });
}, [images, fx, auto]);
```

As you can see, every time one of the attributes in the dependencies array changes, the useEffect hook is run. Inside it I check for the existence of a Swiper instance before destroying it, but for some reason in the first run (no Swiper slider is present) the `swiperRef.current` conditional is true and the `swiperRef.current.destroy(true, true)` call throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: r is null
    R http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-slider/build/blocks/slider/index.js?ver=20f7ca98c8222f0d1ea3:1
    detachEvents http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-slider/build/blocks/slider/index.js?ver=20f7ca98c8222f0d1ea3:1
    destroy http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-slider/build/blocks/slider/index.js?ver=20f7ca98c8222f0d1ea3:1
    edit http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-slider/build/blocks/slider/index.js?ver=20f7ca98c8222f0d1ea3:1
    commitHookEffectListMount http://example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.js?ver=18.2.0:23160
    commitPassiveMountOnFiber http://example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.js?ver=18.2.0:24936
    commitPassiveMountEffects_complete http://example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.js?ver=18.2.0:24901
```

The `console.log(swiperRef.current)` returns this:

```
{
  "__swiper__": true,
  "support": {
    "smoothScroll": true,
    "touch": false
  },
  "device": {
    "ios": false,
    "android": false
  },
  "browser": {
    "isSafari": false,
    "needPerspectiveFix": false,
    "isWebView": false
  },
  "eventsListeners": {
    "init": [
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ],
    "destroy": [
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ],
    "beforeTransitionStart": [
      null
    ],
    "sliderFirstMove": [
      null
    ],
    "touchEnd": [
      null
    ],
    "slideChange": [
      null
    ],
    "toEdge": [
      null
    ],
    "fromEdge": [
      null
    ],
    "lock": [
      null
    ],
    "unlock": [
      null
    ],
    "enable": [
      null
    ],
    "disable": [
      null
    ],
    "click": [
      null
    ],
    "beforeInit": [
      null
    ],
    "setTranslate": [
      null
    ],
    "setTransition": [
      null
    ],
    "transitionEnd": [
      null
    ],
    "virtualUpdate": [
      null
    ]
  },
  "eventsAnyListeners": [],
  "modules": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ],
  "autoplay": {
    "running": false,
    "paused": false,
    "timeLeft": 0
  },
  "navigation": {
    "nextEl": null,
    "prevEl": null
  },
  "params": {
    "init": true,
    "direction": "horizontal",
    "oneWayMovement": false,
    "touchEventsTarget": "wrapper",
    "initialSlide": 0,
    "speed": 300,
    "cssMode": false,
    "updateOnWindowResize": true,
    "resizeObserver": true,
    "nested": false,
    "createElements": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "focusableElements": "input, select, option, textarea, button, video, label",
    "width": null,
    "height": null,
    "preventInteractionOnTransition": false,
    "userAgent": null,
    "url": null,
    "edgeSwipeDetection": false,
    "edgeSwipeThreshold": 20,
    "autoHeight": false,
    "setWrapperSize": false,
    "virtualTranslate": false,
    "effect": "fade",
    "breakpointsBase": "window",
    "spaceBetween": 0,
    "slidesPerView": 1,
    "slidesPerGroup": 1,
    "slidesPerGroupSkip": 0,
    "slidesPerGroupAuto": false,
    "centeredSlides": false,
    "centeredSlidesBounds": false,
    "slidesOffsetBefore": 0,
    "slidesOffsetAfter": 0,
    "normalizeSlideIndex": true,
    "centerInsufficientSlides": false,
    "watchOverflow": true,
    "roundLengths": false,
    "touchRatio": 1,
    "touchAngle": 45,
    "simulateTouch": true,
    "shortSwipes": true,
    "longSwipes": true,
    "longSwipesRatio": 0.5,
    "longSwipesMs": 300,
    "followFinger": true,
    "allowTouchMove": true,
    "threshold": 5,
    "touchMoveStopPropagation": false,
    "touchStartPreventDefault": true,
    "touchStartForcePreventDefault": false,
    "touchReleaseOnEdges": false,
    "uniqueNavElements": true,
    "resistance": true,
    "resistanceRatio": 0.85,
    "watchSlidesProgress": false,
    "grabCursor": false,
    "preventClicks": true,
    "preventClicksPropagation": true,
    "slideToClickedSlide": false,
    "loop": true,
    "loopedSlides": null,
    "loopPreventsSliding": true,
    "rewind": false,
    "allowSlidePrev": true,
    "allowSlideNext": true,
    "swipeHandler": null,
    "noSwiping": true,
    "noSwipingClass": "swiper-no-swiping",
    "noSwipingSelector": null,
    "passiveListeners": true,
    "maxBackfaceHiddenSlides": 10,
    "containerModifierClass": "swiper-",
    "slideClass": "swiper-slide",
    "slideActiveClass": "swiper-slide-active",
    "slideVisibleClass": "swiper-slide-visible",
    "slideNextClass": "swiper-slide-next",
    "slidePrevClass": "swiper-slide-prev",
    "wrapperClass": "swiper-wrapper",
    "lazyPreloaderClass": "swiper-lazy-preloader",
    "lazyPreloadPrevNext": 0,
    "runCallbacksOnInit": true,
    "_emitClasses": false,
    "observer": true,
    "observeParents": false,
    "observeSlideChildren": false,
    "autoplay": {
      "enabled": false,
      "delay": 3000,
      "waitForTransition": true,
      "disableOnInteraction": true,
      "stopOnLastSlide": false,
      "reverseDirection": false,
      "pauseOnMouseEnter": false
    },
    "navigation": {
      "nextEl": ".slider-navigation .slider-next",
      "prevEl": ".slider-navigation .slider-prev",
      "hideOnClick": false,
      "disabledClass": "swiper-button-disabled",
      "hiddenClass": "swiper-button-hidden",
      "lockClass": "swiper-button-lock",
      "navigationDisabledClass": "swiper-navigation-disabled"
    },
    "fadeEffect": {
      "crossFade": true
    },
    "modules": [
      null,
      null,
      null
    ]
  },
  "originalParams": {
    "init": true,
    "direction": "horizontal",
    "oneWayMovement": false,
    "touchEventsTarget": "wrapper",
    "initialSlide": 0,
    "speed": 300,
    "cssMode": false,
    "updateOnWindowResize": true,
    "resizeObserver": true,
    "nested": false,
    "createElements": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "focusableElements": "input, select, option, textarea, button, video, label",
    "width": null,
    "height": null,
    "preventInteractionOnTransition": false,
    "userAgent": null,
    "url": null,
    "edgeSwipeDetection": false,
    "edgeSwipeThreshold": 20,
    "autoHeight": false,
    "setWrapperSize": false,
    "virtualTranslate": false,
    "effect": "fade",
    "breakpointsBase": "window",
    "spaceBetween": 0,
    "slidesPerView": 1,
    "slidesPerGroup": 1,
    "slidesPerGroupSkip": 0,
    "slidesPerGroupAuto": false,
    "centeredSlides": false,
    "centeredSlidesBounds": false,
    "slidesOffsetBefore": 0,
    "slidesOffsetAfter": 0,
    "normalizeSlideIndex": true,
    "centerInsufficientSlides": false,
    "watchOverflow": true,
    "roundLengths": false,
    "touchRatio": 1,
    "touchAngle": 45,
    "simulateTouch": true,
    "shortSwipes": true,
    "longSwipes": true,
    "longSwipesRatio": 0.5,
    "longSwipesMs": 300,
    "followFinger": true,
    "allowTouchMove": true,
    "threshold": 5,
    "touchMoveStopPropagation": false,
    "touchStartPreventDefault": true,
    "touchStartForcePreventDefault": false,
    "touchReleaseOnEdges": false,
    "uniqueNavElements": true,
    "resistance": true,
    "resistanceRatio": 0.85,
    "watchSlidesProgress": false,
    "grabCursor": false,
    "preventClicks": true,
    "preventClicksPropagation": true,
    "slideToClickedSlide": false,
    "loop": true,
    "loopedSlides": null,
    "loopPreventsSliding": true,
    "rewind": false,
    "allowSlidePrev": true,
    "allowSlideNext": true,
    "swipeHandler": null,
    "noSwiping": true,
    "noSwipingClass": "swiper-no-swiping",
    "noSwipingSelector": null,
    "passiveListeners": true,
    "maxBackfaceHiddenSlides": 10,
    "containerModifierClass": "swiper-",
    "slideClass": "swiper-slide",
    "slideActiveClass": "swiper-slide-active",
    "slideVisibleClass": "swiper-slide-visible",
    "slideNextClass": "swiper-slide-next",
    "slidePrevClass": "swiper-slide-prev",
    "wrapperClass": "swiper-wrapper",
    "lazyPreloaderClass": "swiper-lazy-preloader",
    "lazyPreloadPrevNext": 0,
    "runCallbacksOnInit": true,
    "_emitClasses": false,
    "observer": true,
    "observeParents": false,
    "observeSlideChildren": false,
    "autoplay": {
      "enabled": false,
      "delay": 3000,
      "waitForTransition": true,
      "disableOnInteraction": true,
      "stopOnLastSlide": false,
      "reverseDirection": false,
      "pauseOnMouseEnter": false
    },
    "navigation": {
      "nextEl": ".slider-navigation .slider-next",
      "prevEl": ".slider-navigation .slider-prev",
      "hideOnClick": false,
      "disabledClass": "swiper-button-disabled",
      "hiddenClass": "swiper-button-hidden",
      "lockClass": "swiper-button-lock",
      "navigationDisabledClass": "swiper-navigation-disabled"
    },
    "fadeEffect": {
      "crossFade": true
    },
    "modules": [
      null,
      null,
      null
    ]
  },
  "passedParams": {
    "modules": [
      null,
      null,
      null
    ],
    "loop": true,
    "effect": "fade",
    "fadeEffect": {
      "crossFade": true
    },
    "centeredSlides": false,
    "autoHeight": false,
    "observer": true,
    "autoplay": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "navigation": {
      "nextEl": ".slider-navigation .slider-next",
      "prevEl": ".slider-navigation .slider-prev"
    }
  },
  "enabled": true,
  "el": null,
  "classNames": [],
  "slides": [],
  "slidesGrid": [],
  "snapGrid": [],
  "slidesSizesGrid": [],
  "activeIndex": 0,
  "realIndex": 0,
  "isBeginning": true,
  "isEnd": false,
  "translate": 0,
  "previousTranslate": 0,
  "progress": 0,
  "velocity": 0,
  "animating": false,
  "allowSlideNext": true,
  "allowSlidePrev": true,
  "touchEventsData": {
    "focusableElements": "input, select, option, textarea, button, video, label",
    "lastClickTime": 0,
    "velocities": [],
    "evCache": []
  },
  "allowClick": true,
  "allowTouchMove": true,
  "touches": {
    "startX": 0,
    "startY": 0,
    "currentX": 0,
    "currentY": 0,
    "diff": 0
  },
  "imagesToLoad": [],
  "imagesLoaded": 0,
  "initialized": false
}
```

Apparently, a Swiper instance is present but it's not initialized in the first run.
My question is, how can I check for this so the `swiperRef.current.destroy(true, true)` is not called in the first run?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swiper instance object seems to have an `initialized` property which indicates if the Swiper instance is initialized or not.

[image]

You can use this property to check if the Swiper instance is initialized before destroying it. Here's how you can modify your `useEffect` hook -->

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (swiperRef.current && swiperRef.current.initialized) {
        // Destroy Swiper instance when updating.
        swiperRef.current.destroy(true, true);
    }
    // Init Swiper instance.
    swiperRef.current = new Swiper(containerRef.current, {
        modules: [Autoplay, Navigation, EffectFade],
        loop: true,
        effect: fx,
        fadeEffect: {
            crossFade: true
        },
        centeredSlides: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        observer: true,
        autoplay: auto ? {
            delay: 3000,
            disableOnInteraction: false,
            pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
        } : false,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.slider-navigation .slider-next',
            prevEl: '.slider-navigation .slider-prev',
        }
    });
}, [images, fx, auto]);
```

This way, `swiperRef.current.destroy(true, true)` will only be called if the Swiper instance exists and it's initialized.